# LaTeX Beamer; unwanted space/misaligned formula

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing, align

I have to hold a presentation about my final thesis in school and I have an unwanted space. I'm using the beamer package with the `metropolis` theme.
I have an equation in the math environment and the lines are not quite aligned and I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
\begin{frame}[t, plain]{Die Definition der Mandelbrot-Menge}\vspace{4pt}
\begin{align*}
{\only<2->{\transparent{0.6}}z_0\,} &{\only<2->{\transparent{0.6}}= 0,}& {\only<2->{\transparent{0.6}}z_{n+1}\, }&{\only<2->{\transparent{0.6}}= z_{n}^2 + c;}&{\only<2->{\transparent{0.6}} c \in \mathbb{M} }&{\only<2->{\transparent{0.6}}\Longleftrightarrow \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z_n| \leq\, 2}&{\only<2->{\transparent{0.6}}\quad \cite{wiki.mm}}\\
\only<2, 3, 4>{& & {\only<2>{\color{red}}{\only<3->{\transparent{0.6}}z_{n+1}}} &{\only<2>{\color{red}}{\only<3->{\transparent{0.6}}= z_{n}^2 + c}}}\\
\only<3, 4>{{\only<3>{\color{red}}{\only<4->{\transparent{0.6}}z_0\,}}&{\only<3>{\color{red}}{\only<4->{\transparent{0.6}}= 0,}}&{\only<4->{\transparent{0.6}} z_{n+1}\,}&{\only<4->{\transparent{0.6}}= z_{n}^2 + c}}\\
\only<4>{z_0&= 0, & z_{n+1} & = z_{n}^2 + c;&{\only<4>{\color{red}} c \in \mathbb{M}}&{\only<4>{\color{red}}\Longleftrightarrow \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z_n| \leq\, 2}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
```

This is the result on the last slide, where everything is "revealed". The last line seems to have a space in front.

[image: Resulting Slide]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tidied up the code a bit, removing any of the forced spaces that you inserted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,transparent}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t, plain]{Die Definition der Mandelbrot-Menge}
  \begin{align*}
  \only<2->{\transparent{0.6}} z_0 & \only<2->{\transparent{0.6}} = 0,
    & \only<2->{\transparent{0.6}} z_{n + 1} & \only<2->{\transparent{0.6}} = z_n^2 + c; 
    & \only<2->{\transparent{0.6}} c \in \mathbb{M} & \only<2->{\transparent{0.6}} \Longleftrightarrow \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert z_n \rvert \leq 2 
    & \only<2->{\transparent{0.6}} \quad \cite{wiki.mm} \\
    & 
  \only<2->{
    & \only<2>{\color{red}}\only<3->{\transparent{0.6}} z_{n + 1} & \only<2>{\color{red}}\only<3->{\transparent{0.6}} = z_n^2 + c
  } \\
  \only<3->{
    \only<3>{\color{red}}\only<4->{\transparent{0.6}} z_0 & \only<3>{\color{red}}\only<4->{\transparent{0.6}} = 0,
    & \only<4->{\transparent{0.6}} z_{n + 1} & \only<4->{\transparent{0.6}} = z_n^2 + c
  } \\
  \only<4->{
    z_0 &= 0, & z_{n + 1} & = z_n^2 + c; & \color{red} c \in \mathbb{M} & \only<4>{\color{red}} \Longleftrightarrow \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert z_n \rvert \leq 2
  }
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```